# Docker on Synology - Binding to all interfaces

Tags: docker, tcp, synology

I have a MariaDB docker container running on Synology DS918+ and redirects traffic from container port 3306 to external port 3333

When I see how it binds to the port, it seems different than a working example I have for another service that doesn't run on docker

Working :

```
ash-4.3# netstat -nao | grep 5000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Not working:

```
ash-4.3# netstat -nao | grep 3333
tcp6       0      0 :::3333                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

When I try to access port 3333 from my laptop to the remote machine running docker I'm able to do so, the issue is when trying to access the machine's private IP from within the machine itself, this one fails

Any help is appreciated here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, although your docker is only binding to the ipv6 interface(“:::”) not the ipv4(“0.0.0.0”), Docker forbids a loopback connection to its docker-proxy from the host.  I believe this also fails in all networking modes.

If you’re connecting from container to another container, use the container name via the docker-dns and private LAN.  For example, if your MariaDB container is named “maria”, I believe docker’s DNS on 127.0.0.11 offers a lookup for the name “maria” to a 172.*.*.* ipv4 to which other containers may connect if in the same 172.{subnet}.*.*/16 as your MariaDB host.  Connect to “maria” in another container and the tcp magically gets to the right place.

If you’re trying to connect from the docker host to a container, this is a problem that I have resigned to proxying off my router in a hairpin NAT to the same upnp ports that I’ve exported via External Access on Synology, which feels like a poor solution but works today.